# Unresolved attribute reference 'find_all' for class 'list'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
working_days_table = [{"day": 1, "start_at": "09:15", "stop_at": "09:25"},
                  {"day": 2, "start_at": "09:15", "stop_at": "23:25"},
                  {"day": 3, "start_at": "09:15", "stop_at": "09:25"},
                  {"day": 4, "start_at": "09:15", "stop_at": "09:25"},
                  {"day": 5, "start_at": "09:15", "stop_at": "09:25"},
                  {"day": 6, "start_at": "13:42", "stop_at": "15:31"}
                  ]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    time_periods = working_days_table.find_all("day")
```

i got this error..
Unresolved attribute reference 'find_all' for class 'list'

Comment: great, the error says it all, you can't do `.find_all()` on a list object, that's it, either way it doesn't even make sense for some list method to work this way anyways, also what are you trying to achieve? sorting? or what?

Comment: Look at [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), you won't see `find_all`. What do you expect to get from it?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that a list had a method like this for (apparently) searching for `dict`s with a `"day"` key?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

There is no find_all method implemented for list in python. If you are looking to get all values of day, you could do a list comprehension like this

```
time_periods = [x['day'] for x in working_days_table]
```

Comment: This is a helpful answer!

Answer (score 0):

if you want a list like this : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

`time_periods = list() for dict in working_days_table: time_periods.append(dict["day"])`